# Sorting by the first column in a file

Tags: powershell, sorting

I have a file named adat.dat in which I have the following data:

```
1;400;1000000;garden kitchen
11;178;56124;bathroom roof
7;777;20000;oneroom kitchen
10;150;1000000;garage yard
```

I want to sort this from the lowest to the highest by the first column.

So the expected output would be:

```
1;400;1000000;garden kitchen
7;777;20000;oneroom kitchen
10;150;1000000;garage yard
11;178;56124;bathroom roof
```

Here is my code so far:

```
Get-Content adat.dat | Sort-Object
```

Is there an option similar to the Linux `sort -n` option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Import-Csv` for reading the data. If the data don't have headers you can specify your own via the `-Header` parameter. Then sort by the first column using a custom property that casts the string value to an integer (for numeric sorting).

```
Import-Csv 'adat.dat' -Delimiter ';' -Header 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' |
    Sort-Object {[int]$_.a}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, but can you explain what does the {[int]$_.a} mean?

Comment: @TylerJoe - that ensures that the number string is converted to an actual number - which allows a proper numeric sort instead of a string sort. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

here's a method that uses `Get-Content` instead of `Import-CSV`. with large files, the array of objects from `Import-CSV` can get quite large. [*grin*] this avoids some of that by using a scriptblock to create a calculated property for the target of `Sort-Object`.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
1;400;1000000;garden kitchen
11;178;56124;bathroom roof
7;777;20000;oneroom kitchen
10;150;1000000;garage yard
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$SortedInStuff = $InStuff |
    Sort-Object {[int]$_.Split(';')[0]}

$SortedInStuff
```

output ...

```
1;400;1000000;garden kitchen
7;777;20000;oneroom kitchen
10;150;1000000;garage yard
11;178;56124;bathroom roof
```

Comment: @TylerJoe - kool! you are very welcome ... and i enjoyed helping a tad ... [*grin*]